# Internal Ethernet not detected on MacBook 4.1 Mac OSX 10.7.5 (works in Linux Mint)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ethernet, driver

The ethernet port on my MacBook 4.1 doesn't show up on system profiler and isn't available on Network Preferences. This computer is dual boot and the ethernet works fine when I boot into Linux so its not a hardware problem. Any suggestions for how I can reinstall ethernet drivers or get the Mac to reinstall them automatically?

From Linux, using the `lshw` command, these are the details for the adapter, it is the internal, built-in one.

```
*-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: ens5
            version: 00
            serial: 3a:4f:c0:c6:13:a3
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
```

If I use "System Report" to see if the Ethernet detector is detected in Mac OSX I get the message that "This computer does not appear to have any PCI Ethernet cards installed."

I have tried reinstalling Lion but it still doesn't show up. Could my Linux Mint install be somehow locking the Ethernet? The WiFi works fine in Mac OSX and Linux Mint.

Comment: What model is the adaptor?

Comment: I have added information to my question.

Comment: Are you talking about a Mac PRO desktop computer (not a MacBook) and a PCI Network Card? Or a dongle-type external adaptor on a MacBook? What MacOS version is installed? There aren't any 'drivers' outside of macOS itself, unless the vendor of the card supplies them.

Comment: It is a MacBook 4.1 and it is the internal, standard NIC that it came with. The weird thing is that it still works in Linux. I think I am going to reinstall Mac OSX and see if it is detected. It is like there are kexts missing. I was trying to find out if there was a way to force Mac OSX to detect it without reinstalling.

Comment: It is running 10.7.5 which is the maximum supported OS on this device.

Comment: So: not an adaptor -- your built-in Ethernet port doesn't work on macOS? Can you show some screenshots of System Prefs and the Ethernet bit of PRofiler? It should be easy enough to reinstall (without erasing anything).

Comment: Have you tried running `networksetup -detectnewhardware`?

Comment: I just did and no change. Thanks for the tip though, that was just the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: I just re-installed Mac OSX Lion and the Ethernet card is still not detected. It does not show up on System Profiler and doesn't appear as an option when I try to add a new network in Network Preferences.